# The entity type 'xxx' requires a primary key,but i already defined it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

My entity is derived from Entity class, so it should by default have an id of type int, but for some reason EntityFramework does not recognize it. I even tried to manually make my primary key(commented out) but it still won't work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;
using Abp.Domain.Entities;
using Abp.Domain.Entities.Auditing;
using Abp.Timing;

namespace Test.Models
{

    [Table("AppTasks")]
    public class Task : Entity, IHasCreationTime
    {
        //[Key]
        //public int Id { get; set; }

        public const int MaxTitleLength = 256;
        public const int MaxDescriptionLength = 64 * 1024;



        [Required]
        [StringLength(MaxTitleLength)]
        public string Title { get; set; }


        [StringLength(MaxDescriptionLength)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public TaskState State { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public Task()
        {
            CreationTime = Clock.Now;
            State = TaskState.Open;
        }

        public Task(string title, string description = null) : this()
        {
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
        }
    }

    public enum TaskState : byte
    {
        Open = 0,
        Completed = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `EF` or `EF Core`? What is the defination for `Entity`? When did you get this error, run migration or run project? A mini demo which could reproduce your issue would be helpful.

Comment: It was a dumb mistake...My model is called task, the same name as other native model Task, so it got mixed up somewhere, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try using a concrete `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`:

```
public class TaskConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Task>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Task> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(tsk => tsk.Id);
        //builder.HasMany(...) relationships et al.
    }
}
```

And in your `DbContext` definition (or whatever you have called it):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new TaskConfiguration());
}
```

This should definitely configure EFCore in a way, that `Id` will be the primary key for this entity. As an added benefit, you get a bit more flexibility and cleaner code.

Comment: It was a dumb mistake...My model is called task, the same name as other native model Task, so it got mixed up somewhere, thanks anyway